# Why does the pod is running on the master nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

My kubernetes cluster looks as follow:

```
k get nodes
NAME    STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
k8s-1   Ready    master   2d22h   v1.16.2
k8s-2   Ready    master   2d22h   v1.16.2
k8s-3   Ready    master   2d22h   v1.16.2
k8s-4   Ready    master   2d22h   v1.16.2
k8s-5   Ready    <none>   2d22h   v1.16.2
k8s-6   Ready    <none>   2d22h   v1.16.2
k8s-7   Ready    <none>   2d22h   v1.16.2
```

As you can see, the cluster consists of 4 master and 3 nodes.

These are the running pods:

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default        greeter-service-v1-8d97f9bcd-2hf4x        2/2     Running   0          47h     10.233.69.7    k8s-6   <none>           <none>
default        greeter-service-v1-8d97f9bcd-gnsvp        2/2     Running   0          47h     10.233.65.3    k8s-2   <none>           <none>
default        greeter-service-v1-8d97f9bcd-lkt6p        2/2     Running   0          47h     10.233.68.9    k8s-7   <none>           <none>
default        helloweb-77c9476f6d-7f76v                 2/2     Running   0          47h     10.233.64.3    k8s-1   <none>           <none>
default        helloweb-77c9476f6d-pj494                 2/2     Running   0          47h     10.233.69.8    k8s-6   <none>           <none>
default        helloweb-77c9476f6d-tnqfb                 2/2     Running   0          47h     10.233.70.7    k8s-5   <none>           <none>
```

Why the pods greeter-service-v1-8d97f9bcd-gnsvp and helloweb-77c9476f6d-7f76v are running on the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, there is no restriction for Pod to be scheduled on master unless there is a `Taint` like `node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule`.

You can verify if there is any taint on master node using 
`kubectl describe k8s-1`

or
`kubectl get node k8s-secure-master.linxlabs.com -o jsonpath={.spec.taints[]} && echo`

If you want to put a taint then use below

`kubectl taint node k8s-1 node-role.kubernetes.io/master="":NoSchedule`

After adding taint, no new pods will be scheduled on this node unless there is matching toleration on Pod spec.

Read more about Taints and Tolerations [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/)